# ImportError: No module named jupyter_core.command when running jupyter through pyspark in hadoop edge node

Tags: python, pyspark, conda

I am trying to run a jupyter server in a hadoop edge node. For this i am creating a conda environment and running the jupyter through this sh script:

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/home/user/.conda/envs/temp_venv/bin/jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8890 --no-browser'

pyspark \
--deploy-mode client \
--master yarn \
--queue root.queue \
--num-executors 1 \
--driver-memory 1g \
--executor-memory 1g \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python \
--conf spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python \
--conf spark.yarn.dist.archives=hdfs://nodeurl/path_to_env_file>/temp-venv.tar.gz#environment
```

The script works without any problem, but want to put the virtual environment and the script in a shared folder in the edge node so that other colleagues could work with it without having to change or create anything, only copy the script to their personal user folders and run it from there.

What i did is create the virtual environment using this steps:
Activate conda.
Create the virtual environment.
Activate the environment.
Install conda pack and the requirements.
Pack the environment.
Deactivate both the environment and conda.

```
                    "source /opt/conda/bin/activate && \
                     conda remove -n temp_venv --all -y && \
                     conda create -y -n temp_venv python=${pythonVersion} && \
                     conda activate temp_venv && \
                     pip install -r requirements.txt && \
                     conda install --yes conda-pack && \
                     conda pack -f -o /home/${user}/${archive_name} && \
                     conda deactivate && \
                     conda deactivate"
```

After this i copied the tar file into a shared folder in the edge node, extract the tar file there, activate the envionment with source, conda unpack, and change the paths in the run script.
But, when i run the script i receive the error:

```
    from jupyter_core.command import main
ImportError: No module named jupyter_core.command
```

The content of the requirement.txt file that i used to install the requirements is:

```
jupyter
jupyter-core
numpy
pyspark
pandas
```

When i run the script using the originally created virtual environment in the original path, it runs without any problem, but when i use the path to the unpacked environment i have that error.

I have to state also that i am not sudo in that edge node and that install any packages with apt-update or similar is not a posibility.

Any ideas?

Thank you all!

Comment: You're deactivating the environment, so no modules would be found from it

Comment: Yes, but is the to create the environment and to install all the requirements and the environment and the Jupyter server is working perfectly when used the original path where the environment was created, also after deactivating than environment.

Comment: I don't think Jupyter is the issue here, only the `PYTHONPATH` variable that is evaluated when you run your code. In general, I suggest using Ansible to pre-populate your YARN cluster with all necessary Python environments and dependencies to be used with PySpark. Otherwise, you can pass `--py-files` along with `spark-submit`  or `--archives` with a Conda Env - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html

Comment: In general, however, PySpark shouldn't be submitted "as a notebook". You can export the notebook as a regular `.py` file and parameterize any values from it